# How to forward multiple emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to forward multiple emails in Gmail without doing each one individually?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If they're all in a single conversation, then yes: click the **Forward All** link in the top right when viewing the conversation.  Otherwise, no, you cannot bulk-forward random emails.

[image: forward all button in gmail]

In newer versions of Gmail this has moved to the **More** button under **Forward All**, and is only visible when you are viewing a conversation of stacked email (stacked by title replies):

[image: more forward all in gmail]

Comment: confirmed: I can't find any way to do this, and the solution LBushkin proposed no longer works. p.s. we'll always have London

Comment: I think question actuallys asks about forwarding emails in different threads.

Answer (score 21):

There is an easier way. Apply a common label to all the messages that you would like to forward and then use this [Google Scripts](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/) to forward them all to any other email address.

Comment: The link the Google Sheet no longer works - it says I need permission to access the file.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Probably worth mentioning you will lose your label. You can easily add new label as "forwarded" by adding one more column to table and 3 lines of code.

Comment: It works great, but be patient since the forwarding takes a while to start.

Comment: This is amazing! +100 if I could. Hope this will keep on working for a long time...

Comment: As I commented to another answer of yours does not work "Invalid mime type. (line 127, file "labnol")" - the problem is aparently reported in detail here : https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3217

Comment: The scripts have been updated and should no longer throw that error. http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/

Answer (score 3):

You can even try this [script](http://techawakening.org/forward-multiple-emails-on-gmail-with-google-docs/1509/) which I created using Google Apps Script. It helps you forward bunch of emails at one go. It allows you to load and forward first 50 recent emails from your inbox. Please see the discussion thread to know more on how to forward messages tagged to a label as well.

Comment: Please provide some more information, not just a link. The linked web page might disappear some time, leaving your answer useless.

Comment: Just updated with more detailed information :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the whole thing into a PDF by using the print button at the top of all email conversations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153/117311) *"...you cannot bulk-forward random emails"* even now in 2020.
As an alternative though, one can forward them as attachments.

### How to bulk-forward older random emails as attachments

*(without an add-on)*

1. Create a new label and apply it to all messages you want to forward
2. Select this label and also tick all messages on the page on the top left-hand side
3. Click on `Select all xxx conversations in "zzzzz"`

[image]

4. Choose the `Forward as attachment` from the dropdown menu on the

[image]

5. Enjoy